# difference between cgi and modern usage of javascript

Tags: javascript, c, cgi

So In my C introduction class I'm learning CGI, but more I learn about the stuff more I get confused how this is used in modern web development. 
So it's a in the middle between client and severside? meditate information flow? 
for example

```
<form action="color.cgi" method="POST">
```

then cgi is represented on the server side but when user sends http-request color.cgi then the server side does the programming and send it back? 
then isn't color.cgi just on server side?

Or is cgi like a javacript, node.js that's acting on serverside with client language?
I'm very confused

Comment: It is a serverside language. There are a bunch of languages you can run on servers.

Comment: @epascarello oh cgi isn't a language? what is it exactly. I am having hard time understanding it, is it a process that grabs the server side language which is also cgi and display that on the client side?

Comment: What is CGI https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/common-gateway-interface-CGI

Comment: @epascarello this is exactly what I read